# Вставка нового элемента в конец односвязного списка

Tags: c++, списки, односвязный-список

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

struct list
{
    int val;
    list *next;
};

void print(list *a)
{
    list *p = a;
    cout << "Spisok: ";
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        cout << p->val;
        p = p->next;
    }
}

void add(list *&a, list *&head, int data)
{
    list *p = new list;
    p->next = NULL;
    p->val = data;
    list *q = new list;
    q = head;

    if (a == NULL)
        a = p;
    else
    {
        while (q->next != NULL)
            q = q->next;
        q->next = new list;
        q = q->next;
        q->val = data;
        q->next = NULL;
    }
    a = q;
}
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    list *p1 = new list;
    list *head = NULL;
    add(p1, head, 5);
    add(p1, head, 6);

    print(p1);

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Не могу понять, что неправильно с функцией добавления нового элемента в список

Спасибо за советы. Вот исправил.

```
list *init(int a)
{
    list *head = new list;
    head->val = a;
    head->next = NULL;
    return (head);
}

list *add(list *head, int data)
{  
    list *temp, *p;
    p = head->next;
    temp = new list;
    head->next = temp;
    temp->val = data;
    temp->next = p;
    return (temp);
}
```

Comment: @Abyx, не надо там более простых. Надо половину кода выкинуть просто.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Про функцию add:

1. Слишком много параметров. Нужны только список и значение.
2. Не надо там создавать столько мусорных списков. `q=a` и всё.
3. Случай `a==null` обработать отдельно, создав список из одного элемента.

После этого должно заработать.

Ну и ещё, а кто за тебя память освобождать будет?

Comment: А насчет освобождения памяти. Там в сообщении ниже я создал новую функцию add. И как мне теперь освободить память? Создать отдельную функцию освобождения? Или после выхода из функции все само удалится?

Comment: @zof, ничего из созданного тобой через new само не освободится.

Answer (score 2):

Вы, конечно, можете тренироваться со вставкой в конец путем просмотра списка.

Однако, крайне рекомендую просто использовать **два указателя** для представления односвязного списка. Первый на начало, а второй на последний элемент. Меняйте их согласовано и работа с таким списком упроститься. Для пустого списка -- оба NULL. Далее очевидно.

Это если вообще нужны вставки в конец списка. Обычно, на практике, односвязные списки используют там, где порядок элементов не важен.